# Redirect to default action in symfony

Tags: redirect, symfony-1.4

I'm using Symfony 1.4 to build a web application. The home page action for this application is as follows.

```
Module = content
Action = indexAction.php

/localhost/myapp/web/index.php/content/
```

I need to use this action as the defalut action when someone access the application folder using web browser. If someone access the myapp folder as follows.

```
/localhost/myapp
```

It should internally redirect to the

```
/localhost/myapp/web/index.php/content/
```

and access the homepage.

I guess Symfony routing will not work here. Can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Using the symfony routing system, you can define the default module / action for the `/`.

In the `myapp/config/routing.yml`, define the homepage route (it's defined by default):

```yml
# default rules
homepage:
  url:            /
  param:          { module: content, action: index }
```

This way, accessing `/myapp` won't redirect you but you will be on your homepage.

Comment: Nop. After changing it as above it loads homepage when only I go into localhost/myapp/web url. Still it doesn't load the homepage when I go into localhost/myapp folder. it just show only folder structure.

Comment: You didn't configure a vhost to access your website. So going on /webapp will always show you your folder structure.